# Getting transaction events for a Bitcoin cash wallet address using GRPC interface

Tags: node.js, grpc

I have a simple script for listening to Unconfirmed and Confirmed transaction on a Bitcoin cash wallet. I am connecting to a GRPC interface for getting these messages. The script works well and I get the unconfirmed transaction every time a transfer takes place. However, I do not receive any messages for confirmed transaction.

Here's the code I have:

```js
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/bchrpc.proto';
var fs = require('fs');
var bchaddr = require('bchaddrjs');
var axios = require('axios');
var grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
var protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH,
    {keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
    });
var pb = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).pb;


var client = new pb.bchrpc('bchd.imaginary.cash:8335', grpc.credentials.createSsl());

var addr = '<WALLET_ADDRESS>';
console.log(addr);
// Build TransactionFilter & setup live transaction stream
var transactionFilter = pb.TransactionFilter
transactionFilter.all_transactions = false;
transactionFilter.addresses = [addr];

var subscribreTransactionsRequest = pb.SubscribeTransactionsRequest;
subscribreTransactionsRequest.include_mempool = true;
subscribreTransactionsRequest.subscribe = transactionFilter;

var stream = client.SubscribeTransactions(subscribreTransactionsRequest)

function dataHandler(message) {
    console.log('New Transaction');
    var tx = message
    console.log(tx);
    const { type } = tx;
    // map hashes to strings

    switch(type) {
        case 'UNCONFIRMED':
            console.log('Inputs:');
            console.log(tx.unconfirmed_transaction.transaction.inputs);
            console.log('----------------\nOutputs');
            console.log(tx.unconfirmed_transaction.transaction.outputs);
            console.log('---------------------------');
            const h1 = tx.unconfirmed_transaction.transaction.hash;
            fs.writeFileSync('unconfirmed.txt', `${h1.toString('hex')}\n`, { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'a+' });
            break;
        case 'CONFIRMED':
            console.log('Inputs:');
            console.log(tx.confirmed_transaction.transaction.inputs);
            console.log('----------------\nOutputs');
            console.log(tx.confirmed_transaction.transaction.outputs);
            console.log('---------------------------');
            const h2 = tx.confirmed_transaction.transaction.hash;
            fs.writeFileSync('confirmed.txt', `${h2.toString('hex')}\n`, { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'a+' });
            break;
    }
    // post
    axios.post(URL, tx).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status);
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}

// other functions omitted for brevity
stream.on('data', dataHandler);
stream.on('status', statusHandler);
stream.on('end', endHandler);
stream.on('error', errorHandler);
```

The script listens for all events on this given address and on `data` event, invokes `dataHandler` function which prints the transaction information, writes the transaction hash to a file and finally, sends the transaction information to a remote address. On `RST_STREAM` error, the script reconnects to the server after 1 second delay. The script uses `bchrpc.proto` protocol buffer definition from this package [here](https://github.com/gcash/bchd/tree/master/bchrpc).

Is there anything missing in my code that results in this behavior or, is it because the connecting server is unreliable on message delivery? I also tried the following servers with the same results:

1. https://bchd.greyh.at:8335
2. https://bchd.fountainhead.cash:443

Any help on this highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out the issue after looking at other example scripts. I was missing one option in the `subscribreTransactionsRequest` that cause the issue and here's the change that solved the issue:

```js
subscribreTransactionsRequest.include_in_block = true;
```

From the protocol buffer definition:

> // When include_in_block is true, transactions are included when they are confirmed. This notification is sent in addition to any requested mempool notifications.

> bool include_in_block = 4;

Adding the answer here for future reference.